# stretch only certain part in the image when resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm starting to build a `GUI` app in C# (.NET 4.0), and find it a little hard to design the graphics.

I want to have one image background to all panels, and resize it automatically so it fit the panel dimensions.

If the image would just `stretched normally`, then it won't look good since the background image is built in a way of header, frame, center.

So what I want is actually to define the `left, top, right, bottom` anchors of the rectangle in the image that I want to be stretched.

I thought about overriding `PictureBox::OnPaint` and continue from there, but it feels too manual for something that suppose to be pretty simple in GUI developments.

So what is the best approach for resizing only the relevant part of the background image?

Comment: Macking a app with nice GUI with winform is really hard instead of using winform use wpf.most winform controls dose not support transparent background.when you setting form background you can not show most of controls with transparent background.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/377680/Resize-Images-using-9-slices

Comment: @irsog: i dropped WPF when found how much time i'm going to waste on adding the main OCX

Comment: @RoeeK:I think it's easy to work and learn,i have a very bad experience with winform application

Comment: @irsog Please don't abuse the code-formatting as a general highlighting tool. Only use it on content that is actually code.

Comment: @irsog: btw, i added my OCX successfully to WPF :)

Comment: @Bart:Ok,i got it, thanks for guidance,i will not do this again;)